# React dangerouslySetInnerHTML and iframes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a componenet that renders a Wordpress blog post. The blog post contains regular text/html markup and sometimes also includes youtube embeds with an  element. dangerouslySetInnerHTML strips out this iframe. How can I support this type of content.

Answer (score 4):

You can get around this by creating a React element which never updates, but on creation inserts the html you want using regular Javascript. Be aware that this pretty unsafe!

```js
const StaticHtml = React.createClass({
  inject( element ) {
     element.innerHTML = this.props.html;
  },
  
  shouldComponentUpdate() {
     return false;   //prevent React updates as it will get confused by the DOM it didn't put there!
  },
  
  render() {
     return <div ref={ this.inject } />
  }
});

const myHtml = `<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/jUjh4DE8FZA" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`;
ReactDOM.render( <StaticHtml html={ myHtml } />, document.getElementById("app") );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id='app'></div>
```

You can't update the value of the "html" prop because React will get confused, so make sure to destroy and re-create the element whenever html changes (the "key" prop is good for this).